# How do I pass clicked button value to the controller using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to pass clicked button to the controller when user clicked `Next` button from the view/FregihtTool.cshtml

```
@model ThanksTrucking.Models.Shipping


<h2>FreightTool</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("FreightTool", "Shipping")) 

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Calculator</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div row>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="col-md-3" type="button" id="PrintedMaterials" value="1" class="btn btn-secondary " ng-click="levelOU()">Printed Materials </button>
            <button class="col-md-3" type="button" id="Machinery" value="2" class="btn btn-secondary " ng-click="levelCD()">Machinery</button>
            <button class="col-md-3" type="button" id="PaperGoods" value="3" class="btn btn-secondary " ng-click="levelD()">Paper Goods </button>
            <button class="col-md-3" type="button" id="MetalWood" value="4" class="btn btn-secondary " ng-click="levelF()">Metal & Wood Materials </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Now I have FreightController looks like this:

```
// GET: Shipping/FreightTool
    public ActionResult FreightTool()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Post: Shipping/FreightTool
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult FreightTool(int categoryNum)
    {
        int FreightClass = 0;
        switch (categoryNum)
        {
            case 1:
                FreightClass = 50;
                break;
            case 2:
                FreightClass = 60;
                break;
            case 3:
                FreightClass = 70;
                break;
            case 4:
                FreightClass = 80;
                break;
            default:
                FreightClass = 0;
                break;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Shipping", FreightClass);
    }
```

I want to pass `CategoryNum` from the view and the controller handles it and tell which `FreightClass` it is.

Comment: Assuming I understood - you're probably better off with a radio or checkbox (depending on what you need). If you need to stick to `button`,  you're using `Angular` so that would be how you'd "persist" that value (and will handle the submit similarly in client side/Angular). Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your buttons, e.g.:

```
<button class="col-md-3" type="button" id="PrintedMaterials" name="categoryNum" value="1" class="btn btn-secondary " ng-click="levelOU()">Printed Materials </button>
```

Comment: No.. it does not work..
I my submit button on the bottom correct?
`<input type="submit" value="Next" name="categoryNum" class="btn btn-success" />`

Comment: No. Exactly as I showed in my answer: each of your buttons with values corresponding to your switch statement should have that name. That actually means that final submit button is irrelevant. The only way to post a value from a button is to have it submit as well. If you don't want to submit immediately when the user clicks one of those options, then you need to use something like a radio control instead.